# Jiddisches, welches Eingang in die deutsche Sprache gefunden hat

Tags: phrase-request, yiddish

In die deutsche Sprache haben viele jiddische (jüdische) Begriffe Eingang gehalten. Ich würde gerne eine Sammlung starten, und habe Community-Wiki-Fragen so verstanden, als seien diese genau dafür gemacht.

Auf geht's:

- Tacheles reden (Klartext reden)
- koscher sein (sauber, regelkonform sein)
- meschugge (bescheuert)

Comment: "Let's talk tachlis...", as in "let's get down to brass tacks", seems to me to be very much an Americanism; if it's used in German, I don't think it came from Europe. At least I haven't come across "reden tachlis" in a Yiddish text. I see "tachlis" usually in the sense of purpose or destiny, as in the case of someone embarking on a course of life towards a definite goal.

Comment: [Liste deutscher Wörter aus dem Hebräischen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_W%C3%B6rter_aus_dem_Hebr%C3%A4ischen)

Comment: @Marty Green  תּכלית רעדן > takhles redn > "Zweckmäßiges reden, zur Sache kommen"; siehe: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tacheles_reden

Comment: Interesting that your source calls this a 20th-century import into German. I still think this suggest an American provenance: the American "let's talk turkey" was humorously transformed by Jewish immigrants into "let's talk tachlis", which apparently has currency in German as "tachlis reden". It's not a phrase I've encountered in older European literature.

Comment: Oha - die Liste enthält ja einiges überraschendes für mich, konterkariert aber dieses Community-Wiki vielleicht etwas - man müßte es quasi en bloc übernehmen, minus der Spalten, die nicht gefragt sind (qua Beispiel) und minus der Zeilen, die wir schon haben.

Comment: Wird zum  Jahresende nicht auch immer erklärt, dass der "Gute Rutsch" seine Wurzeln im jiddischen hat?

Answer (score 4):

Es zieht wie 'Hechtsuppe' kommt wohl auch aus dem Jiddischen.

Comment: Noch eines fällt mir gerade ein:: 'Kluft', auch wenn es gewisse andere Assoziationen wecken mag.

Comment: Kannst Du Dein eigenes Posting nicht ergänzen? Und: Welche gewisse Assoziation erweckt 'Kluft'?

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39276/woher-kommt-der-ausspruch-es-zieht-wie-hechtsuppe

Answer (score 4):

- Schlamassel (Gegenteil von Masel tov)
- mauscheln (flüstern)
- Mischpoke (die bucklige Verwandtschaft :) )
- malochen (schuften)

schon bin ich mit meinem Jiddisch am Ende

Comment: Tacheles wird schon in meiner Frage gesprochen. Malochen ist jiddisch? Mischpoke habe ich u.a. gesucht, aber kam nicht drauf.

Comment: Malochen is never a verb in Yiddish, but a baal-melocha is a tradesmen, e.g. carpenter, shoemaker, wagon-driver etc. Mauscheln is a funny case; it's not a word in Yiddish, but I understand that it was adopted as a name for the Yiddish-colored underworld slang. Since the au diphthong in Yiddish is pronounced "oy", it seems to mean to carry on in the style of "moyshe".

Comment: @Marty: It seems your're partly right - it isn't a yiddish **verb** but a **noun** stemming from biblical hebrew - see „[Maloche](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maloche)“ from the german Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments on a previous answer we are referred to a list of Yiddish words in German. I have to comment on the entry for "shicksa" (non-Jewish woman). The list derives this from the supposed Hebrew word for Christian, "shiks" (sic). The word actually comes from the Hebrew "shikur", meaning drunk. I have to wonder: is "shicker" not known to German-speakers as slang for inebriated?

Comment: Regarding שיכּור‎: You're right, the Duden has [beschickern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beschickern) as verb and [beschickert](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beschickert) as adjective, describing the result. Regarding שיקסע: I doubt whether your etymology is correct. The [german](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schickse) and [english Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiksa) derive it from שקץ, which sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: You maybe right about the etymology; my version may be a folkloric legend after all. The spelling is a clue (the qof versus the kaph) that something doesn't fit. But what is your Hebrew shkotz? (or sheketz?)

Comment: There's a noun שֶקֶץ in biblical hebrew, (Lev 7, 21; 11, 10-13/20/23/41/42; Jes 66, 17; Ezra 8, 10 - as listed by Gesenius) and also a verb with the root שקץ (e.g. Lev 11, 43; 20, 25). Jastrow's dictionary has some references to rabbinical literature for שֶקֶץ, too, and also for שִקְצָה (shiqzah, pl. שִקְצֵי shiqzey). Just out of curiosity, i checked two ivrith dictionaries (NTC and Langenscheidt), they still have שֶקֶץ in the meaning of "unclean creature", "abomination".

Comment: Maybe we were better off just to leave it as "drunkard".

Comment: "schicker" for inebriated and "schickern" for to get drunk are known in some regions of Germany, e.g. in Münster (Westphalia) where there is a local lingo called "Masematte" which is a blend of Yiddish and Sinti/Roma language that was originally used as a secret language to keep things from the knowledge of the authorities.