# Woher kommt der Ausspruch "Es zieht wie Hechtsuppe"?

Tags: etymology, proverb

Beispiel:

> "Mach doch mal das Fenster zu, hier zieht's ja wie Hechtsuppe!"

Alles, was ich zur Herkunft finden konnte war [dieser Artikel im Abendblatt](https://www.abendblatt.de/ratgeber/wissen/article107774963/Warum-sagt-man-Es-zieht-wie-Hechtsuppe-bei-starker-Zugluft.html), wo es aber nur heißt:

> So soll das jiddische "hech supha" die Bedeutung "starker Wind" haben, womit der Hecht aus dem Rennen wäre. Allerdings ist diese Herleitung äußerst strittig.

und alle vorgeschlagenen Erklärungsversuche werden im Prinzip mit "unwahrscheinlich" bewertet. Hat jemand eine bessere Erklärung, wie der Hecht in die Suppe kommt, und wieso diese eine solch starke Zugluft verursacht?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Meines Wissens wird der Ausspruch oft im Zusammenhang mit Durchzug bei der Zimmerlüftung, am Wasser, auf Bahnhöfen, in Gassen oder Durchgängen benutzt.

Diese Redensart hat weder mit einem Hecht noch mit einer Suppe zu tun! Die "Hechtsuppe" stammt aus dem Hebräischen und heißt eigentlich **hech supha**. Übersetzt bedeutet das `Sturmwind` oder `starker Wind`.

Der hebräische Ausdruck wurde in den jiddischen Sprachgebrauch übernommen. Man sagte also, es zieht wie **hech supha**, wie ein Sturmwind oder starker Wind. Daraus entstand im Laufe der Zeit die Redensart "es zieht wie Hechtsuppe".

British English: “There’s a terrible draught.”
American English: “There’s a terrible draft.”

Comment: Im verlinkten Artikel wird diese Herleitung ebenfalls erwähnt, aber als "äußerst strittig" bezeichnet. Leider lässt sich das Abendblatt nicht darüber aus, WARUM das nun strittig ist. :(

Comment: @Ich finde auch nur diese Erklärung, und sie leuchtet auch ein. Für eine "Strittigkeit" finde ich keinerlei Hinweise. Die hat sich das Abendblatt wohl selbst eingebrockt und muß sie jetzt auch auslöffeln (um im Bilde zu bleiben).

Comment: In der Tat. Die heksupa-(oder wie man es auch schreibt)-Erklärung ist befriedigend, passt ins Ahnenbild einer ganzen Reihe solcher Ausdrücke, die verballhorntes oder missverstandenes Hebräisch sind, und dass das "strittig" sein soll, ist strittig. Das Abendblatt ist ja wohl meschugge! So ein Tohuwabohu!

Comment: @tofro: Ergibt sich die Strittigkeit nicht schon allein aus der Tatsache, dass die wörtliche Bedeutung (Fischsuppe kann man "ziehen lassen") durchaus Sinn ergibt und man daher in Abwesenheit konkreterer Belege (die zumindest auch in dieser Antwort fehlen) davon ausgehen muss, dass es sich bei komplexen Herleitungen über andere Sprachen/Sprachvarianten möglicherweise um Volksethymologien handelt?

Comment: Die Ableitung aus dem Hebräischen ist zwar plausibel, man sollte sie aber nicht apodiktisch zur einzig möglichen Erklärung machen. Zitat aus dem Lexikon der
Redensarten: *Nach einer anderen Erklärung bezieht sich die Redensart darauf, dass Hechtsuppe mit Pfeffer und Meerrettich gewürzt wird und daher recht scharf, ja ein regelrechter „Rachenputzer“ ist.* Ich persönlich finde das nicht wirklich überzeugend, das Ziehen einer Suppe hat wenig mit Zugluft zu tun. Aber Sprachen sind nicht logisch.

Comment: Der Wikipedia-Artikel "Hebräische Sprache" (ja, ich weiß...) sagt: "Mit Sicherheit auszuschließen ist ein hebräischer Ursprung des Ausdruckes Es zieht wie Hechtsuppe, der angeblich auf hech supha („starker Wind“) zurückgehen soll: Das Wort hech existiert im Hebräischen überhaupt nicht, und das mit supha transkribierte Wort סופה (Sturm) wird sufa ausgesprochen. "

Answer (score 0):

Statt eines langen Kommentars (was auf german.stackexchange unerwünscht zu sein scheint) nun eine weitere Antwort.

Ich glaube, dass sich die Herkunft nicht eindeutig klären lässt. Es gibt zwei Ansätze zur Erklärung:

1. Hechtsuppe ist eine Verballhornung des hebräischen *hech supha (= starker Wind)*. Das klingt plausibel, Wind passt zur Zugluft.
   Allerdings hört sich "Mach doch mal das Fenster zu, hier zieht's ja wie ein starker Wind" nicht völlig stimmig an: Ein Wind zieht nicht, er weht oder bläst.
2. Mit Hechtsuppe ist tatsächlich eine Fischsuppe mit Hechtfleisch gemeint. Bei Tee und bei Suppen spricht man von "ziehen lassen", wobei die Bedeutung im Zusammenhang mit Tee eine leicht andere ist als bei Suppen (bei geringer Wärmezufuhr auf dem Herd stehen lassen, ohne dass die Suppe kocht). Das Ziehen einer Suppe hat allerdings nichts mit Zugluft zu tun, der Satz "Mach doch mal das Fenster zu, hier zieht's ja wie eine Suppe" klingt erst einmal unsinnig.
   Es gibt dennoch Gemeinsamkeiten: Zugluft ist kein starker Wind, sondern eine *langandauernde schwache Luftbewegung* im Zimmer; eine ziehende Suppe kocht nicht, sondern wird *längere Zeit* bei *schwacher Hitze* auf dem Herd gelassen. Zugluft fühlt sich unangenehm an, (die mir persönliche unbekannte) Hechtsuppe soll angeblich scharf gewürzt sein und kann daher auch für manche Menschen unangenehm sein. Diese Gemeinsamkeiten führen zwar nicht zur inhaltlichen Stimmigkeit des Bildes, doch idiomatische Redewendung sind oft nicht in sich stimmig und vergleichen manchmal sogar mit Absicht Äpfel und Birnen.
   Im konkreten Fall könnte es also durchaus ziehen wie etwas, das nichts mit Luftbewegung zu tun hat - das wäre dann ein Wortspiel mit den zwei völlig unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen von "ziehen".

Ich favorisiere die erste Erklärung - es ist m.E. unwahrscheinlich, dass in einem Wortspiel mit "ziehen" ausgerechnet der äußerst exotische Begriff "Hechtsuppe" anstelle von "Gemüsesuppe" o.ä. verwendet wird. Eine Verballhorung von "hech supha" ist da wesentlich plausibler.

Und doch bleibt alles spekulativ. Eine einleuchtende Erklärung braucht nicht die richtige zu sein. Schließlich kommen auch alternative Fakten manchmal sehr plausibel daher ...

Comment: "Das Ziehen einer Suppe hat allerdings nichts mit Zugluft zu tun" - ich verstehe nicht, wieso diese Antwort, und auch andere Quellen, auf die man stößt, sich so auf diesen Einwand versteifen. Ich halte ihn für völlig unerheblich, sobald man in Betracht zieht, dass die Redewendung auch einfach auf einem Wortwitz basieren könnte, der eben gerade auf diesem Bedeutungsunterschied bei gleichem Wortlaut aufbaut. Das wäre dann in etwa vergleichbar mit "Sei vorsichtig, der Salat schießt gerade."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Da sind wir uns völlig einig. *Das Ziehen einer Suppe hat allerdings nichts mit Zugluft zu tun* ist auch kein Einwand, die Feststellung weist nur auf die Diskrepanz der Bedeutungen hin, die den Spruch erst einmal unsinnig klingen lassen.  Danach führe ich genau Deinen Gedanken aus: *Im konkreten Fall könnte es also durchaus ziehen wie etwas, das nichts mit Luftbewegung zu tun hat.* Vgl. Dein Salat-Beispiel.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper der Vergleich zieht nicht (sorry), weil eine Waffe ziehen nicht unbedingt zur Schussabgabe führt. Dachte das bedürfte der Erklärung, weil ich es nicht gleich verstanden habe. Allenfalls möchte ich meinen, dass *ziehen* verkürzt für *Abzug ziehen, betätigen* stehen könnteywelches nur deshalb ausscheidet, weil *ziehen* im Kontext Waffe schon besetzt ist. Denktheoretisch bar liegt nun aber beides, darum gings glaub ich.

Comment: @vectory: Den Einwand verstehe ich nicht. Ich hatte keinerlei inhaltlichen Zusammenhang zwischen dem Ziehen der Hechtsuppe und dem Schießen des Salats postuliert. Es ging mir allein darum, dass in beiden Fällen ein Verb benutzt wird, welches (mindestens) zwei recht unterschiedliche Bedeutungen hat, wobei dann innerhalb desselben Satzes absichtlich unterschiedliche Interpretationen in kurzer Folge verwendet werden, um eben den genannten Wortwitz zu erzeugen. ...

Comment: ... Also: "Es zieht [ziehen = Zugluft] wie Hechtsuppe [ziehen = Suppe bei geringer Hitze fertig werden lassen]."; "Der Salat schießt [schießen = schnell aus dem Boden wachsen], sei vorsichtig [schießen = Geschosse abfeuern]!"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, jener Vergleich zieht wie gesagt keine Einsicht. Wenn mein Rettungsversuch nichts dran ändert, bedürfte es weiterer Erklärung. Schließlich ist *Es zieht [ziehen = Zugluft]* ohne weiters schon so bekannt, doch *[schießen = schnell aus dem Boden wachsen]* eben nicht, sondern umgekehrt *aus dem Boden schießen* als Verbalphrase in fester Wendung *= wachsen*, oder wie jetze? Zudem bleibt der Zusammenhang zwischen *ziehen* ¹ und ² genauso wie *schießen* ¹ und ² fraglich (imho abzulehnen, siehe aber DWB: *Geschoss* "Etage", "in die Höhe schießen?) also nicht bindend, kaum nachvollziehbar

Comment: [cont.] Und das kann doch wohl kein Erklärungsansatz sein, *Is halt Unsinn, lulz*, zumindest kein Ansatz der Erwähnung bedarf. Da du es trotzdem erwähntest, habe ich vermutet, da stecke mehr dahinter.

Comment: @vectory: Mir scheint, wir nähern uns einer Erklärung, wieso dir meine Ausführungen bislang unzugänglich sind: "Schließlich ist *Es zieht [ziehen = Zugluft]* ohne weiters schon so bekannt, doch *[schießen = schnell aus dem Boden wachsen]* eben nicht" - doch, doch, "Der Salat schießt.", "Die Bäume schießen." - das sind meines Wissens relativ feste Redewendungen, die (vielleicht nur regional?) ebenso bekannt sind wie "Es zieht."

Comment: Ein hab ich noch übersehen: "Das Ziehen einer Suppe hat allerdings nichts mit Zugluft zu tun", sondern ...? Klar, könnte auch vor der zweiten Lautverschiebung aus so etwas wie *temper-* hervorgegangen sein, genauso gut aber wohl von den Geistern her, die in Form von *Dampfschwaden* den Vorgang versinnbildlichen. Zudem sagt man En. *damp* wenn es kalt und feucht ist (vgl. *Tümpel*? *Sumpf*?), was etwas besser zum Wind passt.

Answer (score -4):

Ich will mutig behaupten, es handele sich um eine Entlehnung, die auf die rekonstruierte Urindogermanische Wurzel *yewH- zurückgeht (“to blend, mix (food), knead”, [en.wiktionary]), die durch Sorbisch vermittelt so unter anderem in *Jauche* [dwds.de] vertreten ist.

Gemeinhin wird diese mit Essen in Verbindung stehen, offenbar vergärtem oder fermentiertem. Insbesondere ist es im Slavischen als Fischsuppe zu deuten, bspw. dialektalisch Lithauisch *jū́šė* (“fish soup”), aber auch ohne solchen in *Soljanka*, sowie im Nord-Germanischen ("cheese"), Latein ("Juice"), Walisisch ("porridge"). [en.wiktionary]

Nun bin ich zwar kein Chef, aber Fischsuppe kippt schnell. Die Fischsuppe ist, wenn ich das richtig gelesen habe, auch eine Delikatesse von gewöhnungsbedürftigem Geschmack bzw. heute auch als Armeleute-Essen angesehen; von dem berühmten Norwegischen verrotteten Fisch steht da allerdings nichts. Auch von Hecht ist im einzelnen nicht die Rede.

Im Gegenteil spricht man bei erwünschter Gärung oder anderen Prozessen auch von *ziehen lassen*. Das passt soweit zum unterstellten Thema. Bei Käse sagen wir aber *reifen*.

Wie ist dann das H anstelle eines Palatals zu erklären. Nun, nichts genaues weiß man nicht. Wo der Ursprung zu verorten sei, ist immerhin nicht bekannt. Einerseits wird beobachtet, dass Slawische Entlehnungen seit eh und jeh Palatale oder ähnliches für H setzen, bspw. *xyž- > Slovak *chyža* aus PGem. *hus- (was an der Stelle weniger überraschen dürfte, da *h */x/ gilt, und so auch *xus notiert wird), so heute noch mit Xelena (Hellena) oder Garry Potter (Harry), so dass eine Entlehnung in umgekehrter Richtung vielleicht ähnlich alterniert (was zu beweisen wäre). Zwar sollte *j schon stimmhaft gewesen sein. Hyperkorremtur wäre trotzdem denkbar, zumal des Wortwitzes wegen. Andererseits findet sich zumindest in Mittelenglisch die Alternation à la *ele, yele, hele* (Aal) verteilt über Dialekte, sodass ich zu erwarten neige, da Frisisch dem Englischen doch recht ähnlich war, hier selbiges vorzufinden, zumal die Küste in Sachen Fisch doch naheliegend ist. Phonetik liegt auch oft im Gehör des Betrachters. Grundlegend auszuschließen ist ein Yiddische Einfluss insoweit auch nicht, da es sich von Böhmen bis Polen zog, usw. usf.

Das t widerum erscheint mir recht leicht aus Allophon *ch* für *š* erklärbar, sprich *Hesch'suppe*, so wie es auch für die hebräische Herleitung aus *hesh supha* angenommen werden müsste, die hier nicht maßgeblich entgegensteht. Der Rest mag dann Wortwitz sein, obwohl ein Witz, der lang und breit erklärt werden muss, sicherlich nicht mehr luftig erscheint.

Die Übertragung auf des Windzugs Luftstrom wäre insoweit vielleicht nicht rein bildlicher Natur. Doch auch dazu fiel mir eben rein zugfällig ein Vergleich auf.

Nämlich leitet Wolfgang Pfeifer *wittern* "riechen" von *Witterung* und *Wetter* aus der Jägersprach her, "'mit Hilfe der Witterung, der wehenden Luft riechen'", so wohl ebenfalls im Nordischen [dwds.de] obwohl offensichtlich nur transitiv *etwas riechen* gemeint ist. Zudem gesellt sich *verwittern*, was ungeachtet der jetzigen Bedeutung angesichts der landläufigen Annahme, bei Gewitter würde die Milch sauer werden, doch dem Gären in nichts nach steht.

Und mit dem gleichen Sinnbild ist es auch nicht unbedingt abwegig, das *ziehen lassen* (von Essen in Vorbereitung) anhand von abziehendem Dampf zu erklären (andernfalls etwa *einziehen*, *durchziehen*, etc.). Damit dürfte sogar eine Nebenbedeutung "riechen" bei "ziehen" zu vermuten sein, die ich aber nicht wirklich bestätigen kann (bestenfalls *zecken* "zwicken, schmerzen" wie *beißen, beißender Geruch*; umgekehrt *abstinken* "verlieren"). Nach reiflicher Überlegung kann zumindest der Revolver-Abzug mit mechanischen Hebeln zum öffnen am Dampf-Abzug verglichen werden, zumal *Ofen* ob mit oder ohne Abzug doch noch der Herkunft ungewiss ist und sich Öffnungen für den Gebrauch von indoor-Feuerstellen ofensichtlich bewährt haben, so gut nämlich dass *window* (Fenster) nunmehr von *vindauga* [en.wiktionary], d. h. *Wind* + *Auge* hergeleitet wird. Fraglich wäre dann ferner, ob *einen Zahn zulegen* dazu gehört, welches recht plausibel mit einer Reihe Sägezähnen erklärt wird, an denen mit einem Ende abgehengt die Länge einer Kette für den Abstand eines Kessels am anderen Ende zum Feuer hin eingestellt wird. S. auch *off*, *abschalten*, *aufschließen*, *der Ofen ist aus*, *zu* etc., ferner *ab-kühlen*, *auf-heizen* (*einheizen* ähnlich *ignite*, richtig wäre *be-heizen*).